# How do I stretch table cell contents to fit the table cell?

Tags: html, css

Image of the problem:

[image]

I want to stretch the bottom `input` to the available space, in this case it would have the same width as the `textarea` above.

Html:

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post the `html/css` code you are using. Have you tried settings the `input` style as `width:100%`?

Comment: I didn't post any code because this is the default behavior. I have no css and the html is just td>input. `width:100%` makes the element too wide, it ignores the padding of the td.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether anything is "default behavior" or not - when you ask this kind of question here, then please _always_ provide a [mre]. It makes no sense efficiency-wise, that everyone here who wants to have a look at the issue, would need to go and create a working example on their own.

Comment: I've provided the example but frankly I don't see why it was necessary. The problem persists with literally no CSS except the borders aren't visible so it's a little harder to explain the problem.

Comment: It is necessary because it might be obvious to you, but it isn't obvious to us, who want to answer your question. By providing an example it makes the debugging process much faster and therefore more people can help you.

Comment: For me (using Chrome) the bottom input does stretch to the container's width but the textarea above does not. Why do you expect them to be of equal width if you don't give them a width?

Comment: When did I say that I expected anything? I'm just asking for help with a problem, but all I got was toxic comments. Had to solve it myself.

Comment: No toxic comments here. If you want faster answers, then put all information in your question. This includes a minimal example. I had no clue what you wanted wihtout the example. With it, I would be able to help you instantly (but now you figured it out yourself already) Dont't blame other users if they don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```css
td > * {
  width: 100%;
}

*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Solved it. Without the box sizing being changed, the children of `td` would ignore `td`'s padding and overflow.